# Escaping square brackets in Regex when using a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this code to replace all opening and closing square brackets which has a matching variable inside:

```
for (var j = 0; j <= temp.length; j++) {
    var re = new RegExp("["+j+"]", 'g');
    imgData = imgData.replace(re, temp[j]);
}
```

The line `var re = new RegExp("["+j+"]", 'g');` doesn't work because I assume the brackets aren't being escaped. Does anyone know how I would escape them, but still be able to have a variable in the pattern? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should escape it with backslashes:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\[" + j + "\\]", "g");
```